# Running casperjs tests with slimerjs

Tags: casperjs, slimerjs

I wrote a few tests with casperjs. They run just fine with phantomjs. However, when I tried to use slimerjs with the following command:

```
casperjs --verbose --engine=slimerjs test create-project-suite.js
```

A small window appers with the SlimerJs logo and version number but the console seems to hang with the following line:

```
Test file: create-project-suite.js
```

Is there anything else I need to do? Here are the version numbers:

```
Mozilla Firefox 28.0
CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3
Innophi SlimerJS 0.9.1
3.8.0-37-generic #53~precise1-Ubuntu
```

**Update:**

I removed code until I got slimerjs to open the browser and execute tests. It seems that it hangs whenever I require a js file (I'm following the page objects pattern):

```
var Login = require('./objects/login');
```

I think [require.paths](http://docs.slimerjs.org/0.9/api/require.html) could be helpful. **Any ideas on how to get around this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using full paths makes slimerjs happy:

```
var path = fs.absolute(fs.workingDirectory + '/objects/login');
var Login = require(path);
```

It is plain simpler to move all modules to the same directory where the script is.

Comment: Yes, i got the same problem with my includes and imports. Example : upload a picture in a form-media- (avatar). With slimer, I had to specify the full path, even if the jpeg file was in the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your command and it works for me, maybe in your file you use an instruction specific to phantom :
http://docs.slimerjs.org/0.8/differences-with-phantomjs.html

But it should open the window(at least the start() ).
Anyway the command is fine.